# npm dependencies pull in different versions of the same package

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, node-modules

Wondering if someone can help me understand why this is happening. I have two npm packages that use `tar-fs@2.1.0` but that package pulls in different versions of `tar-stream`. It is defined in the package.json as ["tar-stream": "^2.0.0"](https://github.com/mafintosh/tar-fs/blob/v2.1.0/package.json#L9) but they resolve to different patch versions when running npm install. Reading about [caret-ranges](https://github.com/npm/node-semver#caret-ranges-123-025-004) I'm not seeing anything to explain this.

I tried deleting the node_modules and lock file, running `npm update tar-stream`, and running `npm install --package-lock-only` to update the lock file based on 'package.json'. Any help is appreciated.

```
$ npm ls tar-stream
project@1.2.0 /Users/akerr/Documents/GitHub/project
├─┬ chrome-aws-lambda@5.3.0
│ └─┬ lambdafs@2.0.0
│   └─┬ tar-fs@2.1.0
│     └── tar-stream@2.1.3
└─┬ puppeteer-core@5.3.0
  └─┬ tar-fs@2.1.0
    └── tar-stream@2.1.4
```